# Customizing .csproj in Unity enable nullable reference types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity3D's 2020.2 release is now supporting C# 8 and nullable reference types. The default way to opt in to this language feature is to put `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in your `.csproj` file, but Unity regenerates `.csproj` and removes this line every time it compiles.

Is there a way to insert custom content into my `.csproj`, or do I need to fall back to the tedious process of starting every file with `#nullable enable`?

Comment: Try a [directory.buildprops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way is to go to File->Build Settings..->Player Settings->Player, scroll down to 'Additional Compiler Arguments' and add `-nullable+`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, at least with Unity 2020.3.8f1.

Comment: @NicFoster Have you already succeeded in enabling the feature in other ways (such as Derek's .csproj edit), so you know that in principle you have C# 8 and it's just the compiler argument being ignored? I tried it in 2020.2 but I wouldn't expect things to change in 2020.3.

Comment: Works in Unity 2021.2, I also used @corinthos answer, for vs code to also play ball.

Comment: Maybe `-Nullable:enable` would be right?

Answer (score 20):

I did the configuration that @Fadeway suggested and it works for building within Unity itself (2020.3.15f2). But it does not work when using outside editors (VSCode in my case).

However, by adding a new file named `Directory.Build.props` along with you `.sln` project file, with the following contents:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It works as expected in the editor and does not get overwritten when regenerating the `.csproj` files from within Unity